# My Media queries are not changing as wanted

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

Currently I'm trying to change the padding of my landing page text, so it pushes my smooth scroll button to the bottom of the page. However the queries work up until (min-width: 600px), and they dont change higher.

Mixins Partial

```
@mixin for-phone-only {
    @media (max-width: 599px) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin for-tablet-portrait {
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin for-tablet-landscape {
    @media (min-width: 899px) {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin for-desktop-up {
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

Landing Page Partial

```
.welcomeTitle {
font-family: $landing-font;
font-size: $landing-header-size-l;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #000;
padding-top: 20%;
@include for-phone-only {
    font-size: $landing-header-size-sm;
}

}

.welcomeText {
@include for-desktop-up {
    padding: 0 20% 21.5% 20%;
    font-size: $landing-text-size-l;
}

@include for-tablet-landscape {
    padding: 0 20% 20% 20%;
}

@include for-tablet-portrait {
    padding: 0 20% 60% 20%;
}

@include for-phone-only {
    padding: 0 20% 50% 20%;
}


}
```

So it applies the tablet portrait query, but when the width goes above 899px, it dose not apply the tablet landscape, or when it goes above 1200px, it dosent apply the desktop query.

Thanks :D

Comment: Check your compiled CSS, the media queries are in this order: `min-width: 1200px`, `min-width: 899px`, `min-width: 600px`. So if you have a width of e.g. 1300px, all three media queries will apply, so the last one (600px) will override all else. To fix this, either change the media query order, or consider using min-width AND max-width in the queries (I'd recommend changing the order though)